# My adapter is in layout even if it is replace by a fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with adapter and replacing a fragmet

My question is .. how to replace  fragment and remove the item in the previous listview?

i try fragment_transaction.begintransation().add(); fragment_transaction.commit(); and the remove

and i also tried fragment_transaction.begintransaction().replace();
fragment_transaction.commit();

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup  container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View wew=getLayoutInflater ().inflate (R.layout.frag2,null);

    GridView listView=wew.findViewById (R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter (new adapter ());

    listView.setOnItemClickListener (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(i==0){
                faculty_fragment faculty_fragment=new faculty_fragment ();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getChildFragmentManager ().beginTransaction ().replace (R.id.frag2,faculty_fragment);

                fragmentTransaction.commit ();


            }
        }

    });
    return wew;

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated (view, savedInstanceState);

}

public class adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return image.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view1=getLayoutInflater ().inflate (R.layout.adapter,null);
        mTextMessage=view1.findViewById (R.id.text1);
        imageView=view1.findViewById (R.id.image1);

        mTextMessage.setText (name[i]);
        imageView.setImageResource (image[i]);
        return view1;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvjwk.png)

Here is the result

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if understood correctly but you are trying to replace a fragment A with fragment B? If yes - then look at this code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(oldfragment).commit();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.yourcontainer, newfragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Here you basically remove the old fragment first and commit then you add your new fragment to your container.

If this is not the answer then maybe it is because your layout **MUST** have a background color/image or something. I've had an experience with 2 items overlapping or rather 2 fragments overlapping eachother and the result was adding a background to the fragment layout.